# Need help for clarification of contradicting EPS data

Tags: stocks

I'm looking at this particular stock PLTR, for 2021 Q2 it shows -0.07 for basic and diluted eps on yahoo but 0.04 on nasdaq site, isn’t eps net income divided by total outstanding shares? I could derive -0.07 from -138,58/1,894,606 but where does this 0.04 come from? Thanks!

https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/PLTR/financials?p=PLTR

https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/pltr/earnings

Answer (score 1):

> it shows -0.07 for basic and diluted eps on yahoo but 0.04 on nasdaq site

This is a GAAP vs non-GAAP issue.

[image]

---

> isn’t eps net income divided by total outstanding shares

If the company doesn't offer preferred stocks which require to pay dividends.

So in this case, the answer is yes.